# Why VolatileImage.getGraphics() create always a new instance of Graphics?

Tags: java, graphics, graphics2d, java-2d

I have the following code

```
 final Graphics2D g2d1 = (Graphics2D) volatileImg.getGraphics();
 final Graphics2D g2d2 = (Graphics2D) volatileImg.getGraphics();
```

Why `g2d1 != g2d2` ??

Why `volatileImg.getGraphics()` create a new instance in each call ??

is there any way to get always the same `Graphics2D` ?

Thanks :)

Comment: `getGraphics` is a left over from the original API, `createGraphics` is the preferred method for obtaining a reference to the graphics context of the image.  In answer to your question, no, there is no way to guarantee that you will get the same `Graphics` context between calls, this is kind of the point.  You don't know if or when then image will be invalidated by the hardware (hence it's volatility).  The real question is why do you need it?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

In fact, volatileImg.getGraphics() is called inside the method paint of my JPanel , and because this method is called frequently in a small period, so I will have so much instances of  Graphics  in my heap, which will invoke several times the GC which reduce the performance of my application.

Comment: Typically you would only use `VolatileImage` in a active painting scenario (where you have control over the paint cycle), given the volatile nature of the image (and having to loop while the contents are not lost), so using it within a `JPanel`'s `paint` method kind screams "wrong" to me.  As to you comment, if you are calling `Graphics#dispose` each time, then you shouldn't have an issue

Comment: Here what I did to improve the performance :
1. volatileImg = component.getGraphicsConfiguration().createCompatibleVolatileImage(width, heigth, Transparency.BITMASK); // I used Transparency.BITMASK for more cpu rapidity

Answer (score 0):

Here what I did to improve the performance of my JComponent View :
1- Use VolatileImage instead of BufferedImage and create a new instance only when the width and the heigth.

```
volatileImg = component.getGraphicsConfiguration().createCompatibleVolatileImage(width, heigth, Transparency.BITMASK); // I used Transparency.BITMASK for more cpu rapidity
```

2- I keep a reference of the Graphics in a field to call Graphics#dispose.

What do you think ?

Comment: I think you're in trouble.  Give the performance enhancements to the overall graphics engine that has occurred over the years, I had the feeling the need of `VolitileImage` had pretty much gone away (I could be mistaken, but I don't tend to have to many issues).  `VolitileImage` has a very particular life cycle, which when used within Swing's passive rendering model, could actually decrease performance.

Comment: You could use [`GraphicsConfiguration#createComatibleImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsConfiguration.html#createCompatibleImage(int,%20int,%20int)) which will create a `BufferedImage` which is using a compatible color model for the given `GraphicsConfiguration`, meaning that when you paint it, it doesn't need to be converted, this has improved performance for me many times

Comment: Any time you're keeping a reference to a `Graphics` object as an instance field, IMHO, you need to be worried

Comment: [This](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2003/09/17/volatileimage-qa) and [this](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2003/09/09/volatileimage-now-you-see-it-now-you-dont) might be of some interest